# How do I programatically edit label widget in the runtime

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, pygtk

How do I programatically edit label widget in the runtime , I am using quickly

I tried

```
self.title=builder.get_object("title")
```

for initialising and

```
def update_Label(self,url):
    self.title.set_text(newlabel)
```

For updating the label ,But it won't work

!.Honestly I dont know what I am doing . I am an absolute beginner in python

Comment: `Gtk.Label.set_text(str)` is the correct way, so please add some sample code and a full traceback.

Comment: @Timo I updated my question

Comment: What is the traceback (error) you receive? Is `self.title` a `Gtk.Label`? Is `newlabel` defined in your namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo:

```
def update_Label(self,url):
    self.title.set_text(newlabel)
```

to

```
def update_Label(self,url):
    self.title.set_text(url)
```

Comment: Sorry I already fixed it , It was a typo of the previous command

Comment: Newlabel was a temporary string for test the method